# How do I remove first and last item from linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

Here are my codes that I have been doing so far, just the two small parts which need to remove first and last item from linked list that I got confused. (python)

```
class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None 

    def __str__(self):
        list1 = []
        st1 = '['
        curr = self.head
        while curr != None:
            list1.append(curr.get_data())
            curr = curr.get_next()
            list1.append(' ')
        for x in range(0, len(list1) - 1):
            st1 += str(list1[x])
        st1 += ']'
        return st1

    def __iter__(self):
        return LinkedListIterator(self.head)

    def removefirst(self):
        ??

    def removelast(self):
        ??
```

Comment: actually the code i have been done is longer than this but when i try to post the question it got error so i have to delete some of my code

Comment: If you really have an `UnorderedList`, `removefirst` is the same as `removelast` as `removeany`.

Comment: I can use .set_next in order to remove last item but I can't use set_next on removing first item in a linked list

Comment: `self.head = self.head.get_next()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use snake_case instead of a camelCase in Python.

```
def remove_first(self):
    temp = self.head
    self.head = self.head.get_next()
    del temp

def remove_last(self):
    previous = None
    current = self.head
    while current.get_next() is not None:
        previous = current
        current = current.get_next()
    previous.get_next() = None
    del current
```